# Trying to trim and fade multiple wav files in remote folder with SOX

Tags: batch-file, audio, sox, windows-console

I'm trying to create a file so that when I drag and drop a selection of wav files onto the batch script, it a. copies the wavs to a subdirectory (/webclips), replaces the spaces with underscores, then tries to trim all of the new wav files from the beginning to 45 seconds out.  Eventually I'll fade them out...
Right now the script is copying fine but then giving a couple errors when it runs the trim command:
sox WARN wav: Premature EOF on .wav input file
sox WARN trim: Last 2 position(s) not reached (audio shorter than expected).

The new wavs files are (incorrectly) 1Kb in size.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my script

```
set FOLDERPATH=%~dp0
set FILEPATH=%~dp1
mkdir "%FILEPATH%webclips"
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (copy %%A "%FILEPATH%webclips")
cd  "%FILEPATH%webclips"
for %%j in (*.*) do (
set filename=%%~nj
set filename=!filename:.=_!
set filename=!filename: =_!
if not "!filename!"=="%%~nj" ren "%%j" "!filename!%%~xj"
)
c:
cd/
CD "Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2"
for %%A in ("%FILEPATH%webclips\*.wav") do sox "%%A" "%FILEPATH%webclips\%%~nxA" trim 0 45
pause
```

Comment: What will be the result after adding `(` before `sox`

Comment: it's the same.  I've removed the errant ")" typo...

Answer (score 0):

In last line, `sox` overwrote the searched .wav file. For `sox`, it cannot do like that.

So the operation of copying original .wav file to subfolder can be removed.

`!variable!` is delayed format and have to be declared `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` before it.

the batch file can also be simplified as the following,

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (%*) do (
  if not exist "%%~dpawebclips\" md "%%~dpawebclips\"
  set file_name=%%~na
  set file_name=!file_name: =_!
  set file_name=!file_name:.=_!
  ren %%a !file_name!%%~xa
  "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe" "%%~dpa!file_name!%%~xa" "%%~dpawebclips\!file_name!%%~xa" trim 0 45
)
pause
exit /b
```